# Handling Media Files in Android by installed apps

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, android-audiorecord

I have an app which records Audio and video. Then there is a list in the app which displays these recorded files. When user clicks on one of this file, I would like to display an option of apps that user can choose to play this clicked file. An example of it is shown below.

[image]

All the examples I have looked on internet is of using a media player which I am already doing but I would like the pause, stop etc function to be handled by an already available app in the users device.

Is this possible to do? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `Activity` which handles Audio and Video should have this in `AndroidManifest`.
The below `intent-filer` is for **Audio** files, similarly you can add for **Video** files for the same `Activity`.

```
<activity ...>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

EDIT:
For your `Activity`

Suppose you show a list of audio files and user is suppose to click one. So when the user clicks some item. You just need to set the result.
Ex.

```
    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().setData(YOUR_URI));
```

The 2nd param is just the data which we need to pass to the calling `Application` basically we pass the `URI` of the data.

EDIT 2: The `RESULT_OK` is inherited variable of `Activity`. You don't need to define it.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: But what should I do after user clicks on one of the recordig on the list. Is there a specific call I need to make?

Comment: @Sahil I edited my answer. You can find the solution.

Comment: Great, I will give it a go now... Thanks a lot

Comment: I gave this a go but it is not working as expected. nothing happens when list item is clicked. My toast message is shown which is linked to a list item click method.

Comment: @Sahil Did you call `setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().setData(YOUR_URI));` inside the click listener of your list?

Comment: Yes I did. My List is a fragement, But just to try I did add a test button and onclick of this test button setResult is applied. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sahil As your working with `Fragment`. Use `getActivity().setResult(...);`

Comment: Yes I have posted the answer below. I have finally got it done but in a slightly different manner.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by readin up on the internet.

First prepare the file location and then open an intent with the data at this location

```
Uri fileURi = Uri.parse(tempFileURi); //i.e. /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.sahilsaid.appname/files/Music/Recording200.3gp
File file = new File(fileURi.toString());

 if (file.exists()) {
    Uri finalFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(finalFileUri, URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(finalFileUri.toString()));
    startActivity(intent);

 }
```

You will also need to modify your AndroidManifest.xml file and add intent-filter as suggested above by @Aky

```
   <activity
        android:name=".exampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_example">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For more info visit this article:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/20/video-playing-with-android-media-player